# How to remove padding on different screen size with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a hero class where I have:

```
.hero{padding: 90px 30px}
```

I have this, but when there is a bigger screen, I want to remove the padding completely so I tried:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1150px) {
  .hero{
    padding: none !important;
  }
}
```

I tried this but it came back with "invalid property value". Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `padding:0`. Your attempt is not working because `none` is not a valid [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding). A valid one is either a [`<length>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) or a [`<percentage>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/percentage).

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 1150px) {
  .hero {
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```